# How to rollback my DB changes after a commit?

Tags: database, oracle, flashback

I did a DB update without using a where clause and commit without taking any backup. All the rows in the table are updated. Is there any way to rollback the changes?

The DB is a Oracle SQL one. Please help.

Comment: You cannot rollback what has already been commited

Comment: try using flashback https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9012.htm

Comment: Why do you have both `sql-server` and `oracle` tags together. My answer is specific to Oracle database.

Comment: My bad. I had updated nearly 2K rows and was desperate and added all these tags to my qyestion. By the way, I used the flashback by TIMESTAMP and retrieved the data. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do it using **[Flashback](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/flashback-dml-changes-on-a-table-after-commit/)** feature.

**1.Flashback by SCN**

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_name
AS OF SCN scn_number;
```

**2.Flashback by TIMESTAMP**

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_name
AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('the timestamp value');
```

To get current_scn and systimestamp, query :

```
SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM v$database;
```

Let's see an example :

To flashback the table to the old scn, use **`FLASHBACK TABLE..TO SCN`** clause.

```
SQL> DROP TABLE string_ex PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE string_ex (sl_ps_code VARCHAR2(20) );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14ASM0002');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0018');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0019');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0062');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201277 29-OCT-14 03.02.17.419000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201280 29-OCT-14 03.02.22.785000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201282 29-OCT-14 03.02.26.781000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14ASM0002
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062

SQL>
```

**I have four rows in the table**.

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE string_ex ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**Row movement is required.**

```
SQL> DELETE FROM string_ex WHERE ROWNUM =1;

1 row deleted.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062
```

**I deleted a row now and committed the changes.**

```
SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE string_ex TO SCN 13818123201277;

Flashback complete.
```

**Flashback is complete**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14ASM0002
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062

SQL>
```

**I now have my table to old state and the row is back**