# Records Deleted. Commit executed. Can we have that records back from anywhere?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, undo, flashback

Recovered Records Should be up to date as when they were deleted.

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to recover deleted records after a commit?

Comment: Do you have flashback enabled, and were they deleted recently - within your flashback window?

Comment: Yes. But records Should be up to date as when they were deleted. @Tunaki

Comment: No flashback  enabled..  @AlexPoole

Comment: You're looking at a point-in-time recovery then, assuming you have proper backups and archived redo logs; but you'll lose changes after that point. There's no magic solution (without the magic of flashback).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rollback my DB changes after a commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309730/how-to-rollback-my-db-changes-after-a-commit)

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the **FLASHBACK QUERY**.

I answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27309814/3989608

You could go back as far as depending on the settings of the **UNDO_RETENTION** parameter.

A quote from T.Kyte regarding flashback query:

> flashback query has been enabled in the database for many many many years.
>   We call it Multi-versioning and it gives us our consistent read and non-blocking reads.
>
> That means -- you've been doing flashback query for years.
>
> You do not need to "enable it", it is an intrisic feature/function of the database that 
>   you cannot in any way "disable"!
>
> It is ALWAYS on.

Link from AskTom https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6135698985750