# How to revert the committed changes in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I had written a plsql block which will delete the duplicate data in a table. Since the logic that I have written is wrong, some original data is also deleted and the changes are committed. Please advice me on how I can revert the committed data changes and also advice me on how to delete duplicates

Comment: you may look up `as of timestamp systimestamp - interval ..` for the first part of the question. There are lots of samples for the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flasback query will be used to revert the commited changes in oracle. Please google on how to user falsback query in oracle

Answer (score 2):

#### You could do it using Flashback feature.

**1.Flashback by SCN**

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_name
AS OF SCN scn_number;
```

**2.Flashback by TIMESTAMP**

```
SELECT column_list
FROM table_name
AS OF TIMESTAMP TO_TIMESTAMP('the timestamp value');
```

To get current_scn and systimestamp, query:

```
SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP
FROM v$database;
```

Let's see an example:

**To flashback the table to the old scn, use `FLASHBACK TABLE..TO` SCN clause.**

```
SQL> DROP TABLE string_ex PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE string_ex (sl_ps_code VARCHAR2(20) );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14ASM0002');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0018');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0019');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO string_ex (sl_ps_code) VALUES ('AR14SFT0062');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201277 29-OCT-14 03.02.17.419000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201280 29-OCT-14 03.02.22.785000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT current_scn, SYSTIMESTAMP FROM v$database;

         CURRENT_SCN SYSTIMESTAMP
-------------------- --------------------------------------------
      13818123201282 29-OCT-14 03.02.26.781000 PM +05:30

SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14ASM0002
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062

SQL>
```

**I have four rows in the table.**

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE string_ex ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

**Row movement is required.**

```
SQL> DELETE FROM string_ex WHERE ROWNUM =1;

1 row deleted.

SQL>
SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062
```

**I deleted a row now and committed the changes.**

```
SQL> FLASHBACK TABLE string_ex TO SCN 13818123201277;

Flashback complete.
Flashback is complete

SQL> SELECT * FROM string_ex;

SL_PS_CODE
---------------
AR14ASM0002
AR14SFT0018
AR14SFT0019
AR14SFT0062

SQL>
```

**I now have my table to old state and the row is back**

**By:** [How to rollback my DB changes after a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309730/how-to-rollback-my-db-changes-after-a-commit)